# Deep Neural Network - Order of the Parameters to tune

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to this DNN field and I am fed up with tunning hyperparameters and other parameters in a DNN cause there are a lot of parameters to tune and it is like a multivariable analysis without the help of a computer. How human can move towards the highest accuracy that can be achieved for a task using DNN due to the huge number of variables inside a DNN. And how will we know what accuracy is possible to get by using DNN or do I have to give up on DNN?  I am lost. Help is appreciated.

Main problems I have :

```
1. What are the limits of DNN / when we have to give up on DNN

2. What is the proper way of tunning without missing good parameter values
```

Here is the summary I got by learning theory in this field. Corrections are much appreciated if I am wrong or misunderstood. You can add anything I missed. Sorted by the importance according to my knowledge.

for overfitting -

```
1. reduce the number of layers
2. reduce the number of nodes of layers
3. add regularizers (l1/ l2/ l1-l2) - have to decide the factors
4. add dropout layers and -have to decide the dropout factor
5. reduce batch size
6. stop earlier
```

for underfitting

```
1. increase the number of layers
2. increase number of nodes of layers
3. Add different types of layers (Conv, LSTM, ...)
4. add learning rate decay (decide the type and parameters for the type)
5. reduce the learning rate
```

other than that generally we can do,

```
1. number of epochs (by seeing what is happening while model training)
2. Adjust Learning Rate
3. batch normalization -for fast learning
4. initializing techniques (zero/ random/ Xavier / he)
5. different optimization algorithms
```

auto tunning methods

```
- Gridsearchcv - but for this, we have to choose what we want to change and it takes a lot of time.
```

Comment: You forgot the parameter that is, to my mind, the most important of all : the learning rate ! If your learning is too slow, increase it. If you have the feeling your final performance is not good enough, decrease it.

Comment: sir, you are correct and i forgot to add it. My opinion was learning rate can be changed by seeing how model performs on the task and if learning is too slow, increase lr, learning is overshot, decrease lr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: You should experiment **a lot**!

Long Answer: At first, you may be overwhelmed by having plenty of knobs that you can tweak, but you gradually become experienced. A very quick way to gain some intuition on how you should tune the hyperparameters of your model is trying to replicate what other researchers have published. By replicating the results (and trying to improve the state-of-the-art), you acquire the intuition about deep learning.
I, personally, follow no particular order in tuning the hyperparameters of the model. Instead, I try to implement a dirty model and try to improve it. For instance, if I see that there are overshoots in validation accuracy, which might be an indicator of the fact that the model is bouncing around the sweet spot, I divide the learning rate by ten and see how it goes. If I see the model begins to overfit, I use early stopping to save the best parameters before overfitting. I also play with dropout rates and weight decay to find the best combination of them in order to have the model fit enough while maintaining the regularization effect. And so on.
To correct some of your assumptions, adding different types of layers will not necessarily help your model not to overfit. Moreover, sometimes (especially when using transfer learning, which is a trend these days), you cannot simply add a convolutional layer to your neural network.
Assuming you are dealing with computer vision tasks, Data Augmentation is another useful approach to increase the amount of available data to train your model and perform its performance.
Also, note that Batch Normalization also has a regularization effect. Weight Decay is another implementation of l2 regularization that is widely used.
Another interesting technique that can improve the training of neural networks is the One Cycle policy for learning rate and momentum (if applicable). Check this paper out: https://doi.org/10.1109/WACV.2017.58

Comment: Thank you very much, sir... can you give me an idea, where I can give up on DNN... which means is my train acc is 99.9% (by overfitting) and my val_acc is 80%... what can be the limit of the val_acc I can possibly get if I work harder. (for a task which has a human error ->0). How I know there is nothing to do with the DNN and i have to move for a another method (SVM/ Randomforest /...)

Comment: There is no clear answer to this. The only thing I can tell you is that for computer vision you probably don't need to switch to SVM or Random Forests. Instead, you should change your DNN architecture and see if it helps or not. Also, I can't predict what accuracy you could achieve in your task. Nobody can.  Good Luck